# Store hex data in DB using Django and Postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql, binary-data

I've run into a situation where I have binary data (created using `os.urandom(BLOCK_SIZE)`) that I need to store in a Postgres database using Django Models.

I've read several references to how Django doesn't yet support Bytea (VARBINARY) field types yet.  I found a reference [here](http://django-postgresql.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields/bytea.html) but don't know where to get that library (django_postgresql).

I'm currently using Python 2.7 and Django 1.4 on Ubuntu 12.04 - if that helps.

I've read some suggestions as a way around this is to convert my data to hex before storing it.

```
import binascii
key = binascii.hexlify(value)
```

Ok, now what?  I tried to save this value to the database but get errors:

`invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xd6c2`

Ok, which data field type should I use to do this?

`key = models.TextField(max_length = 200)`?

`key = models.CharField(max_length = 200)`?

`key = models.???(max_length = 200)`???

I'd like to stay away from creating my own [custom field type](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/).  First, I'm pretty new to Django and wouldn't feel comfortable doing this yet.  Second, I'm pretty new to databases so I'm not sure where to start on defining something like this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is this data being used for and how big is `BLOCK_SIZE` and is it likely to change?

Comment: @ Jon Clements This data represents a key for cryptography.  `BLOCK_SIZE` in this case is 32 Bytes (`os.urandom(32)`).  The `BLOCK_SIZE` will not change.

Comment: Check if `type(key)` is `str` or `unicode`. You may need to `key.encode('ascii')` if unicode...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get unicode errors when you save the key value, you're doing it wrong. `binascii.hexlify()` returns a simple string of hex characters, which will not give you the "invalid byte sequence".

For more efficient storage, use base64 encoding:

```
import base64
mymodelinstance.key = base64.b64encode(raw_key_value)
```

And to decode:

```
raw_key_value = base64.b64decode(mymodelinstance.key)
```

You can just use a CharField of length `BLOCK_SIZE * 2` to hold hex data, or `4 * ( BLOCK_SIZE / 3)` for base64.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem.  You were right about the error, I was doing it wrong.  In short, it was just a syntax error when writing to the database.